# Yeoman angular-generator does not work with foundation

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, yeoman, bower

I am developing an application using yeoman's angular-generator and zurb-foundation.

Foundation styles are working great but foundation.js is not working. I can not use modals, dropdowns, topbar menu, anything.

I'm generating my project like so:

```
mkdir ang
cd ang
yo angular
bower install -s foundation
grunt serve
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue is usually caused by the `$(document).foundation()` block being called before all the angular stuff gets to the view.

I would recommend using [angular-foundation](https://github.com/madmimi/angular-foundation) for foundation components. Either that or making your own directives because that would take care of the $scope synchronization with the DOM.